# Can't get query to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a database containing 3 tables (member, boat, boatType) and in the method below two of them is affected. What I want is to list all boats that's registered on a member, but there's a problem with the code (at least with the SQL, but I suspect that's not all).

Thanks in advance.

**boatHandler.php:**

```
public function GetMembersBoats($memberId) {

    $query = "SELECT b.boatId, b.length, bt.type
                  FROM boat AS b
                      INNER JOIN member AS m
                          ON b.memberId = m.memberId
                              WHERE m.memberId = ?
                      INNER JOIN boatType AS bt
                          ON b.boatTypeId = bt.boatTypeId
                      GROUP BY b.boatId";

    $stmt = $this->m_db->Prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $memberId);

    $boats = $this->m_db->GetBoats($stmt);
}
```

**database.php:**

```
public function GetBoats($stmt) {
    $boats = array(
            0 => array(),
            1 => array(),
            2 => array()
        );

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($boatId, $length, $type);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        array_push($boats[0], $boatId);
        array_push($boats[1], $length);
        array_push($boats[2], $type);
    }

    $stmt->Close();

    return $boats;
}
```

#### Affected tables:

- **boat:** boatId, boatTypeId, length, memberId
- **boatType:** boatTypeId, type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause has to be listed after the table references. You have to move the `WHERE m.memberId = ?` to the end of the table references after the `FROM` and `JOIN`s like so:

```
SELECT b.boatId, b.length, bt.type
FROM boat AS b
      INNER JOIN member AS m
          ON b.memberId = m.memberId

      INNER JOIN boatType AS bt
          ON b.boatTypeId = bt.boatTypeId
WHERE m.memberId = ?
GROUP BY b.boatId
```

Comment: `+1` i'm 2 seconds late..hehe

Comment: Correct (as opposed to my) SQL would include length and type in the group by clause.

Comment: @podiluska Sorry I didn't noticed that. But as far as I know, mysql does permit that unlike sql server. Any way this solved the OP problem.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal It does. but it shouldn't. :)

Comment: @podiluska I heard many times here in SO from some MYSQL gurus that this isn't true for mysql. and it is ok to list fields in the select statement with no aggregate functions.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Mysql allows it, because Mysql is a crock of ****, not because it's good practice. :)

Answer (score 1):

as you in on clause, simply replace 'where' by 'and':

```
SELECT b.boatId, b.length, bt.type
              FROM boat AS b
                  INNER JOIN member AS m
                      ON b.memberId = m.memberId
                          AND m.memberId = ?
                  INNER JOIN boatType AS bt
                      ON b.boatTypeId = bt.boatTypeId
                  GROUP BY b.boatId
```